# Finding projections

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not completely sure about this kind of question:

$$\begin{align}V&=\operatorname{span}\{(2,2,2,1),(1,0,1,1),(1,4,1,-1)\}\\
W&=\operatorname{span}\{(2,2,2,1),(1,0,1,1),(1,4,1,-1),(2,1,0,0)\}\\
U_1&=\operatorname{span}\{(2,1,0,0)\}\\
U_2&=\operatorname{span}\{(3,5,1,-1)\}\\
w&=(4,0,0,1)\\
W&=V \oplus U_1\\
W&=V \oplus U_2\end{align}$$

I want to do the following:

- Find the projection of the vector $w$ onto $V$ with respect to the first decomposition and with respect to the second decomposition
- Find the orthogonal projection of the vector $w$ onto $V$.

I'm not sure about the difference between those things. I think that for the orthogonal projection I should do:

$P_V(w)=\langle(4,0,0,1),(2,2,2,1)\rangle(2,2,2,1)+\langle(4,0,0,1),(1,0,1,1)\rangle(1,0,1,1)+\langle(4,0,0,1),(1,4,1,-1)\rangle(1,4,1,-1)$

Is that correct? and how do I approach the first item?

My intuition says:

$$w - \langle w,(3,5,1,-1)\rangle(3,5,1,-1)$$

For the second decomposition for example. Is that true?

Thank you.

Comment: Your equation for the orthogonal projection would be correct --- if the generating set given for $V$ was orthonormal. But it wasn't, so it isn't. One approach is to find an orthonormal basis for $V$, so you can use the formula you have tried to use. Do you know how to find an orthonormal basis? Have you studied Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you. What about the projection with respect to the decompositions? Do I need to apply Gram Schmidt in those cases too or it's just for orthogonal projections? (I'm a bit confused with the definitions)

Comment: I think "projection of $w$ onto $V$ with respect to $V\oplus U$" means find $v$ in $V$ and $u$ in $U$ such that $w=v+u$, and I think the simplest way to do this is to express $w$ as a linear combination of the four vectors, the three that span $V$ and the one that spans $U$.